# Enterprise Architect - relation between observer and processed object

Tags: uml, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I have quick and simple question about specific class diagram model issue.

I have Observer and Observable classes and objects representing the notification (types of objects that are sent to the Observer) - see model below

**ObjectType1** and **ObjectType2** are classes whose instances are sent to the Observer as an argument of method `update(Observable o, Object arg)` by **ObservableSubject** instance.

[image]

My question is, how to model the relation between **ObjectType1**|**ObjectType2** and **Observer** class?

Comment: As long as you don't tell us, how they are related: as you like.

Comment: Hi, i updated my question, but i think it was clearly defined before edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableSubject` should be an `<<interface>>` and both `ObjectTypeX` realize that interface. So the have the method `update` to inform the `Observer`.

You should show the method `update` inside `ObservableSubject`. That would have made your question clear from the beginning.